# Is there a name for this constant?

Tags: riemann-zeta

$$\prod_{n=2}^\infty \zeta(n)=2.294856591673313794183$$

Is there a name for this constant, and what are some if its properties?

Comment: Apparently it gives the average number of abelian groups of a given order. And apparently this is "well-known". http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/tex/ECRH/ECRH.pdf

Comment: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=2.2948565916733) and [WMW](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelianGroup.html).

Comment: I don't think you can find closed form, since $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \log \zeta(ns) = \sum_p \sum_{m=1}^\infty p^{-sm} (\sigma_{-1}(m)-\frac{1}{m})$. The only hope I see is transforming it into a contour integral, and finding a trick.